# Common interface with different return types

Tags: java, interface

I am creating a small app working on file system. The user can choose a directory and than, application get one of the possible result (examples):

- return number of lines in all *.java files
- return number of lines in all *.java files without comments
- return number of all classes
- return number of `i`fs etc...

Because I want to follow the single responsibility principle, and because all these functionalities have something in common, I want to create one class for each functionality (using commons.io DirectoryWalker) under a common interface. That's why I find such an interface useful:

```
**
 * Common interface for counting classes (lines, words, classes, etc...) 
 */
public interface Counter {
    /**
     * count required things starting from startDirectory, recursively or not, 
     * and consider only specified extensions 
     */
    int count(File startDirectory, boolean recursive, List<String> fileExtensions);
    int count(File startDirectory, boolean recursive);
}
```

Now, the user can simply create some collection with counters, create and add new counter easily, iterate etc.

Questions:

1. Of course it is just a simplification, but do you think that the main idea of using an interface here is reasonable?
2. Maybe I will have some methods which will return something different than `int` - for example, `Map` with pairs, or a list of the ten longest files. In this case my interface is not correct. What should I do in such case? Maybe the interface's method should return Object like this:

   ```
   Object count(File startDirectory, boolean recursive);
   ```

   But this seems bad to me as it will lead to some unfriendly casting when parsing the returned value (Object). I can create some special DTO object like the below which will contain all possible "answers":

   ```
   public class CounterDTO {
       public int numerOfLines; // used for counters counting lines
       public int numberOfIfs;  // used for counters counting if statements
       public Map<File, Integer> linesInFiles;  // ... File -> number of lines
       public List<File> longestFiles; // used for indicating files with maximal number of lines
       // and so on...
   }
   ```

   Then the interface method would look like:

   ```
   CounterDTO count(File startDirectory, boolean recursive);
   ```

   Is this OK or is there a better way?

Comment: The fact, that classes behave similarly doesn't mean they need to implement the same interface. You need an interface, if some code will have to work with any of those classes. How are you going to use this interface? Maybe you will call `count` only on concrete types and this interface will only get in your way.

Comment: `recursive` flag looks suspicious. It looks like every class will have to implement its own directory traversing. Maybe you should have a separate class for that. It would take any existing `Counter` and apply it to all files in specified directory.

Comment: @Banthar Usage will be probably like this: user have a checklist with many counter types (counting options). After user selects required counter, then it app will simply invoke all count methods from all counter via interface.

Comment: @Banthar Thanks for " It looks like every class will have to implement its own directory traversing". That's a very good point I've forgot to ask in post...

Comment: Please consider editing your title to describe what your code does. This will help reduce the amount of "is this code ok" questions and contribute to make CR Google-discoverable :)

Answer (score 2):

**Normally when you need "different return types"**, you can use [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/). However, since you want these `Counter`s to be in a List of some sort, using generics goes out the window since a List cannot be defined properly to contain both `Counter<List<File>>` and `Counter<Integer>`, so the only solution would be to have a `List<Counter<?>>` in which case the reason for using generics in the first place is lost.

Your `CounterDTO` class makes sense if a `Counter` counts more than one of the things. If the counter is only meant to return an int **or** a list of files, then using a `CounterDTO` is quite useless since many fields will be **null**.

**Regarding Banthar's comment** to your question, you could modify your existing interface to

```
int count(List<File> files);
```

It would then be the job for **a single utility method** (or two) to create a list of files from these parameters: `File startDirectory, boolean recursive, List<String> fileExtensions`.

**As for the question about return type**... If you need an interface for this or not depends on how you are using these counters. And also: Which possible counters are there? If you have one counter for returning total line count and one for returning a `Map<File, Integer>` of line counts, then you don't need two different counters. Since you need to know all the line counts in all the files to know the total line count, using a `CounterDTO` makes perfect sense here.